# How can I delete videos off iTunes Library on my computer but keep them on my iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

My computer is running low on space, so after I sync my films to my iPhone, I want to delete them from my computer.

How can I do this, without having iTunes sync this deletion back to my iPhone the next time I connect my iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your iPhone’s **Summary** page in iTunes, *check* `Manually manage videos` (if you don’t use iTunes Match or MUSIC this option will read `Manually manage music and videos`).

[image: Manually manage videos]

This will let you decide what gets synced and what doesn’t.